# Return parent record with only children that meet a certain criteria

Tags: linq, entity

I have two tables.  One is batch and it has a child table of requests.

I need to return a batch record where one of it's children has a status of 0 and process of false.  The lambda expression I have returns all parents that have any children that meet the criteria.  The issue is that it's including children that don't meet the criteria.

Here is my expression

```
        List<Batch> batches = _DC.Batches.Where(
         c => c.Requests.Any(d => d.Processed == false && d.ApprovalStatus.ApprovalStatusId == 0))
              .Select(c => c).ToList();
```

How do I get this to return only requests that meet the criteria but still return the parent if any meet the criteria?

EDIT: 
This is what I'm doing now after turning off lazy loading.

```
            List<Batch> batches = _DC.Batches.Where(
                c => c.Requests.Any(d => d.Processed == false && d.ApprovalStatus.ApprovalStatusId == 0))
                .Select(c => c).ToList();

        foreach (Batch batch in batches)
        {
            _DC.Entry(batch).Collection(c=>c.Requests).Query().Where(c=>c.ApprovalStatusId== 0 && c.Processed == false).Load();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of starting at the Batches table, start at the Request table.  Pseudo code:

```
var requests= _DC.Requests.Where(x => x.Processed == false && x.ApprovalStatusId == 0);
```

That code will get you all of the requests where Processed == false && ApprovalStatusId == 0.  From there, if you want to get information on the batches just do:

```
foreach(var r in requests) {
   var batch = r.Batch;
   //do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.  Unfortunately that returns a batch for each request that is in the db including the request that has a approvalstatusID != 0.  This results in .  I added a distinct onto the end and I get the same results I do with my original code.

Comment: Are you trying to find batches where ALL the Requests have Processed == false && ApprovalStatusId == 0?  I'm confused on what the expected result should be.

Comment: Sorry. Let me try to explain it better.  I'm looking for all of the batches where there is any request with processed == false and ApprovalStatusID == 0.  Then in the Batch.Request property I only want to see requests where processed== false and approvalstatusID == 0.   What I get is list of batches where any of the requests meet the above criteria but when I delve into the request property of the batch it's full of requests that have a approvalstatusID == 1 or 0.

Comment: Is is possible that I'm expecting too much of linq and need to break this into two operations?   Get the batches then remove the requests that don't meet my requirement?

Comment: Thank you.  It sounds like I was expecting too much in trying to do it in one statement.

Comment: checkout my updated answer and see if that does't meet your needs.  It's not that you're existing too much from LINQ, I think it's more a chance for you to learn how LINQ returns the data you're asking of it.

Comment: you're welcome, it might be possible to do it in a single statement but it's probably going to generate some really ugly sql.  I would stick with this approach.